# How to access child view-model object from parent view-model?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, devexpress

```
   // Child View model
    public class ChildViewModel
    {
        public ChildModel CurrentChild { get; set; }
        private readonly List<ChildModel> _childList = new List<ChildModel>();
        public ChildViewModel()
        {
           CurrentChild = new ChildModel();
        }
        public static ChildViewModel Create()
        {
           return ViewModelSource.Create<ChildViewModel>();
        }
        public void SaveMessage()
        {
           _childList.Add(ChildMessage);
        }
    }

    //parent ViewModel public class ParentViewModel {
        public ParentViewModel() {
            Child = ChildViewModel.Create();
        }
        public virtual ChildViewModel Child { 
            get;
            protected set;
        }
     }
//Parent View 
fluentApi.BindCommand(simpleButton , x => x.Child.Save());
//Child View 
fluentApi.SetObjectDataSourceBinding(ChildModelBindingSource, x => x.CurrentChild);
```

I have bind controls in usercontrol with object CurrentChild in child view-model.
and when I click on simpleButton in parent view to call save method in child view-model but the model object (CurrentChild) is null(it's not update it's vlaue).
so how can I update parent view-model property base on child view model is changed.

Comment: Please provide a **complete and compilable** version of the code. From the current version is not clear how the View-parts are related to each other and how they share the ViewModel instances.

Comment: Here is a sample project code @DmitryG

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ecDet3qgHDG1skWXn1mjZ06eP0yj76F2?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the corrected code which works well for me:

View side:

```
var fluent = mvvmContext1.OfType<ParentViewModel>();
fluentApi.BindCommand(btnSave, x => x.Child.Save());
fluentApi.SetObjectDataSourceBinding(childModelbindingSource, x => x.Child.CurrentChild);
```

ViewModels side:

```
// Child View model
public class ChildViewModel {
    readonly List<ChildModel> _childList = new List<ChildModel>();
    public ChildViewModel() {
        CurrentChild = new ChildModel();
    }
    public static ChildViewModel Create() {
        return ViewModelSource.Create<ChildViewModel>();
    }
    public ChildModel CurrentChild {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public void Save() {
        _childList.Add(CurrentChild);
    }
}
// Parent ViewModel 
public class ParentViewModel {
    public ParentViewModel() {
        Child = ChildViewModel.Create();
    }
    public virtual ChildViewModel Child {
        get;
        protected set;
    }
}
public class ChildModel { 
    // ...
}
```

**Update:**
To make your sample work, you should pass the child ViewModel instance into ChildView *before* the initializing bindings:

```
// MainView
public MainView() {
    InitializeComponent();
    if(!mvvmContext1.IsDesignMode)
        InitializeBindings();
}
void InitializeBindings() {
    var fluent = mvvmContext1.OfType<MainViewModel>();
    fluent.BindCommand(simpleButton1, x => x.ChildViewModel.Save());

    var childView = new ChildView(fluent.ViewModel.ChildViewModel); // pass the ViewModel
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(childView);
}
// Child View
public ChildView(ChildViewModel viewModel) {
    InitializeComponent();
    if(!mvvmContext1.IsDesignMode) {
        mvvmContext1.SetViewModel(typeof(ChildViewModel), viewModel); // before any bindings
        InitializeBindings();
    }
}
void InitializeBindings() {
    var fluent = mvvmContext1.OfType<ChildViewModel>();
    fluent.SetObjectDataSourceBinding(childModelBindingSource, x => x.ChildData);
    fluent.BindCommand(simpleButton1, x => x.Save());
}
```

The main note:
**When you are running into an issue with using the DevExpress products**, please [contact the DevExpress support directly](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create). Not Google, not SO. 
You can provide their guys with any samples and all additional details of your issue and then they provide you with guaranteed and correct solution.

Comment: childModelbindingSource is not at parent view. It's already bind the control in user control in child view so SetObjectDataSourceBinding is implement in child view

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ecDet3qgHDG1skWXn1mjZ06eP0yj76F2?usp=sharing

Comment: I cannot get child object from child view-model to execute in parent view model. here is a sample

Comment: Please, check my updated answer. Not in SO rules, but just a gesture of goodwill...

Comment: It's working now but how to get data from parent view-model by child view-model?